# Laravel. Passing arguments through delete request

Tags: php, html, laravel, url

I'm using LaravelCollective form to delete an employee:

```
 {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'action' => ['EmployeesController@destroy', $employee->id, $company->id]]) !!}

                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::submit('Remove employee', ['class'=>'btn btn-danger']) !!}
                </div>

 {!! Form::close() !!}
```

and want to pass 2 arguments: employee id and company id.

My route:

```
Route::delete('/employees/{employee}/{company}', 'EmployeesController@destroy');
```

My controller function:

```
public function destroy($id, $companyId)
{
    Employee::find($id)->delete();

    if($companyId == 0)
        return redirect('/employees');
    else
        return redirect('/companies/' . $companyId . "/edit");
}
```

I'm getting an error that I'm passing only 1 parameter. Where is the problem?

Comment: You access it something like this `/employees/1/2`?

Comment: @nmfzone yes, like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
// named route
Route::delete('employees/{employee_id}/{catetory_id}', 'EmployeesController@destroy')->name('employees.destroy');

// form using named route
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => ['employees.destroy', $employee->id, $company->id]]) !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::submit('Remove employee', ['class'=>'btn btn-danger']) !!}
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the params in an array, try something like this.

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'action' => ['EmployeesController@destroy', [$employee->id, $company->id] ]]) !!}

            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::submit('Remove employee', ['class'=>'btn btn-danger']) !!}
            </div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: Yeah, I think this is the correct answer. Could you provide the stack trace for your current error? @FaustasButkus

Answer (score 0):

The variable name should match the route parameter. Try something like this in your controller:

```
public function destroy($employee, $company)
{
    Employee::find($employee)->delete();

    if($company == 0)
        return redirect('/employees');
    else
        return redirect('/companies/' . $company . "/edit");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did not help. Same error for array to string conversion

Comment: No, the code is same as your explanation. Not the jordy garcia answer. I just double check the core code, that what you're doing is correct.

Comment: Could you try to `dd('something')` before the `Employee:find()` ? Just to make sure the error does not come from the `redirect()`.

Comment: I get this error right away I enter the edit page. This error comes from the form itself I guess. Because before when the parameters were set apart the edit page was rendered and when I send the PUT request then i got the error, but now  when I put them into array I get this array conversion into string error

Comment: Are you sure the error comes from code in your explanation? Not from the other? Sorry, I can't identify more because I only see the piece of code.

Comment: I found the problem. I had Route::resource() for my employees and my new delete route wasn't overriding it. Thank you for help.